# Jquery slide to visibility hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to achieve something like :

```
$("#left").hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000)
```

However I do not want the div to be hidden I want it to keep up space so I want have the visibility hidden like:

```
$("#left").css('visibility','hidden')
```

Yet still achieve the same effect as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'd do

```
$parent = $('#left').parent(); //store the parent of the element in a variable
$('#left').clone() //clone the existing element
.appendTo($parent) // insert it into the current position
.css('visibility','hidden') //set it's visibility to hidden
.end().end() //target the initial element
.slideUp() //do any slide/hide/animation that you want here, the clone will always be there, just invisible
```

This could be horrible, but it's the only way I could think of solving the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/skyrim/j2RWt/4

Try this:

```
var $content = $("#left");
var offset = $content.offset();
$("<div></div>").css({
    width: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    left: offset.left,
    top: offset.top,
    height: $content.outerHeight(),
    backgroundColor: "White"
}).appendTo("body")
.animate({
    width: $content.outerWidth()
}, 1000, function () {
    $content.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

---

EDIT

So, after learning what the actual need was (:p), this method basically place another div over the original element.  I've tested it on IE...and I'll edit this with an update after I do further testing on other browsers!

---

EDIT

Only Chrome seems to be having an issue with getting the correct height.

---

Added a callback which removes the makes visibility hidden (as LEOPiC suggested) and removes the slideout div

Comment: I think the OP really wants that slide-out to the right effect, not only to hide the element.

Comment: @LEOPiC - ah, ic...thnx for the input

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in very simple way. There is really a nice tutorial **[here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)** to animate in different direction. It will surely help you. try this

```
$('#left').animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

EXAMPLE : http://jsfiddle.net/2p3FK/2/

**EDIT:** One more solution, this is very simple to move the div out of window with `left margin`

```
$("#left").animate({marginLeft:'1000px'},'slow');
```

EXAMPLE : http://jsfiddle.net/2p3FK/1/